# Batching operation error (V3 API)

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

When trying to make a QBD batch request using the new V3 api, I'm getting errors that seem to indicate there are missing elements. I took the example in the docs (http://bit.ly/154KPWs) and simplified it:

```
<IntuitBatchRequest xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
   <BatchItem  bId="bid1">
    <Customer>
       <Organization>false</Organization>
       <FullName>John Doe</FullName>
       <DisplayName>John Doe</DisplayName>
       <PrintOnCheckName>John Doe</PrintOnCheckName>
    </Customer>
  </BatchItem>
  <BatchItem  bId="bid2">
    <Customer>
       <Organization>false</Organization>
       <FullName>Jane Doe</FullName>
       <DisplayName>Jane Doe</DisplayName>
       <PrintOnCheckName>Jane Doe</PrintOnCheckName>
    </Customer>
   </BatchItem>
</IntuitBatchRequest>
```

Here's the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-09-18T02:06:03.974Z"><Fault type="Validation"><Error code="0"><Message>UnmarshalException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'BatchItem'. One of '{&quot;http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3&quot;:BatchItemRequest}' is expected.]</Message></Error></Fault></IntuitResponse>
```

Am I missing something or the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one working customer create request body.

```
Request Body : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitBatchRequest xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <BatchItemRequest operation="create" bId="bID1">
        <Customer>
            <Organization>false</Organization>
            <Title>Job1</Title>
            <GivenName>TestCustomer1</GivenName>
            <MiddleName>SampleMiddleName1</MiddleName>
            <FamilyName>SampleSurname1</FamilyName>
            <Suffix>Sr.</Suffix>
            <CompanyName>ABCDGTech</CompanyName>
            <DisplayName>TestDataCustomerc7bceSample1</DisplayName>
            <PrintOnCheckName>Print name</PrintOnCheckName>
            <Active>true</Active>
            <PrimaryPhone>
                <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
                <FreeFormNumber>(650)111-1111</FreeFormNumber>
                <Default>true</Default>
                <Tag>Business</Tag>
            </PrimaryPhone>
            <AlternatePhone>
                <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
                <FreeFormNumber>(650)111-1111</FreeFormNumber>
                <Default>false</Default>
                <Tag>Business</Tag>
            </AlternatePhone>
            <Mobile>
                <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
                <FreeFormNumber>(650)111-1111</FreeFormNumber>
                <Default>false</Default>
                <Tag>Home</Tag>
            </Mobile>
            <Fax>
                <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
                <FreeFormNumber>(650)111-1111</FreeFormNumber>
                <Default>false</Default>
                <Tag>Business</Tag>
            </Fax>
            <PrimaryEmailAddr>
                <Address>test@testing.com</Address>
            </PrimaryEmailAddr>
            <BillAddr>
                <Line1>Testing1</Line1>
                <Line2>Testing2</Line2>
                <Line3>Testing3</Line3>
                <City>Bangalore</City>
                <Country>India</Country>
                <CountrySubDivisionCode>KA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
                <PostalCode>560097</PostalCode>
            </BillAddr>
            <ShipAddr>
                <Line1>Shipping1</Line1>
                <Line2>Shipping1</Line2>
                <Line3>Shipping1</Line3>
                <City>Bangalore</City>
                <Country>India</Country>
                <CountrySubDivisionCode>KA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
                <PostalCode>560097</PostalCode>
            </ShipAddr>
            <ContactName>Contact Name</ContactName>
            <AltContactName>Alternate Name</AltContactName>
            <Notes>Testing Notes</Notes>
            <Job>false</Job>
            <Balance>100055.55</Balance>
            <OpenBalanceDate>2013-09-18</OpenBalanceDate>
            <BalanceWithJobs>5055.5</BalanceWithJobs>
            <CreditLimit>200000</CreditLimit>
            <AcctNum>Test020102</AcctNum>
            <ResaleNum>40</ResaleNum>
            <JobInfo>
                <Status>InProgress</Status>
                <StartDate>2013-09-16</StartDate>
                <ProjectedEndDate>2013-09-23</ProjectedEndDate>
                <EndDate>2013-09-23</EndDate>
                <Description>In Progress</Description>
            </JobInfo>
        </Customer>
    </BatchItemRequest>
    <BatchItemRequest operation="create" bId="bID2">
        <Customer>
            <Organization>false</Organization>
            <Title>Job2</Title>
            <GivenName>TestCustomer2</GivenName>
            <MiddleName>SampleMiddleName2</MiddleName>
            <FamilyName>SampleSurname2</FamilyName>
            <Suffix>Sr.</Suffix>
            <CompanyName>ABCDGTechTech</CompanyName>
            <DisplayName>TestDataCustomerc48aaSample2</DisplayName>
            <PrintOnCheckName>Print name</PrintOnCheckName>
            <Active>true</Active>
            <PrimaryPhone>
                <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
                <FreeFormNumber>(650)111-1111</FreeFormNumber>
                <Default>true</Default>
                <Tag>Business</Tag>
            </PrimaryPhone>
            <AlternatePhone>
                <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
                <FreeFormNumber>(650)111-1111</FreeFormNumber>
                <Default>false</Default>
                <Tag>Business</Tag>
            </AlternatePhone>
            <Mobile>
                <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
                <FreeFormNumber>(650)111-1111</FreeFormNumber>
                <Default>false</Default>
                <Tag>Home</Tag>
            </Mobile>
            <Fax>
                <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
                <FreeFormNumber>(650)111-1111</FreeFormNumber>
                <Default>false</Default>
                <Tag>Business</Tag>
            </Fax>
            <PrimaryEmailAddr>
                <Address>test@testing.com</Address>
            </PrimaryEmailAddr>
            <BillAddr>
                <Line1>Testing1</Line1>
                <Line2>Testing2</Line2>
                <Line3>Testing3</Line3>
                <City>Bangalore</City>
                <Country>India</Country>
                <CountrySubDivisionCode>KA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
                <PostalCode>560097</PostalCode>
            </BillAddr>
            <ShipAddr>
                <Line1>Shipping1</Line1>
                <Line2>Shipping1</Line2>
                <Line3>Shipping1</Line3>
                <City>Bangalore</City>
                <Country>India</Country>
                <CountrySubDivisionCode>KA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
                <PostalCode>560097</PostalCode>
            </ShipAddr>
            <ContactName>Contact Name</ContactName>
            <AltContactName>Alternate Name</AltContactName>
            <Notes>Testing Notes</Notes>
            <Job>false</Job>
            <Balance>100055.55</Balance>
            <OpenBalanceDate>2013-09-18</OpenBalanceDate>
            <BalanceWithJobs>5055.5</BalanceWithJobs>
            <CreditLimit>200000</CreditLimit>
            <AcctNum>Test020102</AcctNum>
            <ResaleNum>40</ResaleNum>
            <JobInfo>
                <Status>InProgress</Status>
                <StartDate>2013-09-16</StartDate>
                <ProjectedEndDate>2013-09-23</ProjectedEndDate>
                <EndDate>2013-09-23</EndDate>
                <Description>In Progress</Description>
            </JobInfo>
        </Customer>
    </BatchItemRequest>
</IntuitBatchRequest>
```

Endpoint - https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/{RelamID}/batch?

In your batch request,[ **operation="create"** ] is missing in BatchItemRequest tag.

**Code** - `batchOperation.addEntity(customer, OperationEnum.CREATE, "bID" + i);`

Hope It will be useful.

**Edit** Adding Sample Query (using V3 java devkit)

```
Item item = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(Item.class);
Item itemIn = getItemFields();
String query = select($(item.getId()), $(item.getDescription())).where($(item.getId()).eq(itemIn.getId())).generate();
QueryResult queryResult = service.executeQuery(query);
```

Generated req URI - `https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/791926875/query?query=SELECT+Id%2C+Description+FROM+Item+WHERE+Id+%3D+%27null%27&`

Method - GET

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is helpful indeed. Please do correct the docs as that's our main reference point and incorrect samples are very costly.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. I will definitely raise a doc change request. Thanks.

Comment: Manas, how do you add a query to the batch?

Comment: There are two methods for this.
batchOperation.addQuery(query, bId);
batchOperation.addCDCQuery(arg0, arg1, arg2);
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0/0004_asynchronous_calls/batch_process
Thanks

Comment: I'm developing on the force.com platform using Apex. Could you just add a query to the request body above? Thanks.

Comment: I missed the last msg. Sorry for that. I've added a sample query. Hope it will be useful. Thanks